# NullReferenceException When setting a parram

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to solve this problem on my own, but the error keeps on showing up: `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`
The lines that are causing this are :

```
line = new LinearLayout(this);
lisCount++;
lis[lisCount] = line;
line.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Rgb(12, 155, 12));
var lineParams = line.LayoutParameters; // <- line with exception
lineParams.Width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent;
```

Can Anyone help me?

EDIT:
Changed to:

```
line = new LinearLayout(this);
line.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent,
     ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);lisCount++;
lis[lisCount] = line;
line.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Rgb(12, 155, 12));
var lineParams = line.LayoutParameters;
lineParams.Width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent;`
```

The problem now is that the LinearLayout disappears alltoghether

Comment: My money is on `lineParams` being null. Voting to close for lack of context.

Comment: tell me what do you need and i`ll povide...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: More context, where do you assign a value to `lineParams`?

Comment: The variable "line" must be null in 5th line of code you posted. Please, check if there is another parallel code (another thread) that is clearing "lis" or "line" variables.

Comment: I am pretty sure it does not...

Comment: @BogdanConstantin: What you're "pretty sure" of is irrelevant.  What you validate from debugging matters.

Comment: "pretty sure" means that i`ve debugged it...

Comment: What is the purpose of this code anyways? Are you making a list of something? If so, why are you not using a ListView?